# Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.InvocationException: Received a HTTP response with an unexpected status code: ServiceUnavailable

Tags: c#

I'm currently working on a project where I'm using the `JeringTech/Javascript.NodeJS` library to invoke JavaScript code from C# using Node.js. However, I'm encountering an issue. Here's the relevant code snippet:

```
   string javascriptModule = @"
module.exports = (callback, x, y) => {
    var result = x + y;
    callback(null, result);
}";

// Invoke javascript
int result = await StaticNodeJSService.InvokeFromStringAsync<int>(javascriptModule, args: new object[] { 3, 5 });
```

And the error message I'm getting is:

```
Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.InvocationException: Received a HTTP response with an unexpected status code: ServiceUnavailable.
   at Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.HttpNodeJSService.TryInvokeAsync[T](InvocationRequest invocationRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Jering.Javascript.NodeJS.OutOfProcessNodeJSService.TryInvokeCoreAsync[T](InvocationRequest invocationRequest, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I'm unsure about the cause of this error and how to resolve it. Node version 16.14.1

edit: now i find in first try i see another error like this:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. (127.0.0.1:10809)'

SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Comment: https://github.com/JeringTech/Javascript.NodeJS/issues/91

Comment: this issue not have any solution